# jest test fails with expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

'     Hello, New to Jest Testing, im trying to create a test that validates running a function. however, it fails, but im not exactly sure why. other tests with the same structure have passed. any insight please will be appreciated.

import React from 'react';

```
import Feed from 'components/Feed/Feed';
import feedContent from 'components/Feed/mock-data.json';

describe('Component', () => {
    let spyFuncArr = ['_renderCards'];
    let wrapper;
    let instanceSpies = {};


  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<Feed content={feedContent} />);
    instanceSpies = createSpyArr(spyFuncArr, Feed);
  });


  describe('--- Rendering ---', () => {
    it("Component Renders", () => {
      expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
  });

  describe('--- Functionality ---', () => {
    it("should run _renderCards", () => {
      expect(instanceSpies["_renderCards"]).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

Comment: The question doesn't contain the code you're testing. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: What is `createSpyArr`? Also why are you testing private method call? This is implementation detail that has nothing to do with what component should do nor how it should behave.